# Spark dynamic frame show method yields nothing

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

So I am using AWS Glue auto-generated code to read csv file from S3 and write it to a table over a JDBC connection. Seems simple, Job runs successfully with no error but it writes nothing. When I checked the Glue Spark Dynamic Frame it does contents all the rows (using .count()). But when do a .show() on it yields nothing.

.printSchema() works fine. Tried logging the error while using .show(), but no errors or nothing is printed. Converted the DynamicFrame to the data frame using .toDF and the show method it works. 
I thought there is some problem with the file, trying to narrow to certain columns. But even with just 2 columns in the file same thing. Clearly marked string in double quotes, still no success.

We have things like JDBC connection that needs to be picked from Glue configuration. Which I guess regular spark data frame can't do. Hence need dynamic frame working.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
spark = glueContext.spark_session

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options('s3', {'paths': ['s3://bucket/file.csv']}, 'csv', format_options={'withHeader': True,'skipFirst': True,'quoteChar':'"','escaper':'\\'})

datasource0.printSchema()
datasource0.show(5)
```

Output

```
root
|-- ORDERID: string
|-- EVENTTIMEUTC: string
```

Here is what the converting to regular data frame yields.

```
datasource0.toDF().show()
```

Output

```
+-------+-----------------+
|ORDERID|     EVENTTIMEUTC|
+-------+-----------------+
|      2| "1/13/2018 7:50"|
|      3| "1/13/2018 7:50"|
|      4| "1/13/2018 7:50"|
|      5| "1/13/2018 7:50"|
|      6| "1/13/2018 8:52"|
|      7| "1/13/2018 8:52"|
|      8| "1/13/2018 8:53"|
|      9| "1/13/2018 8:53"|
|     10| "1/16/2018 1:33"|
|     11| "1/16/2018 2:28"|
|     12| "1/16/2018 2:37"|
|     13| "1/17/2018 1:17"|
|     14| "1/17/2018 2:23"|
|     15| "1/17/2018 4:33"|
|     16| "1/17/2018 6:28"|
|     17| "1/17/2018 6:28"|
|     18| "1/17/2018 6:36"|
|     19| "1/17/2018 6:38"|
|     20| "1/17/2018 7:26"|
|     21| "1/17/2018 7:28"|
+-------+-----------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Here is the some data.

```
ORDERID, EVENTTIMEUTC
1, "1/13/2018 7:10"
2, "1/13/2018 7:50"
3, "1/13/2018 7:50"
4, "1/13/2018 7:50"
5, "1/13/2018 7:50"
6, "1/13/2018 8:52"
7, "1/13/2018 8:52"
8, "1/13/2018 8:53"
9, "1/13/2018 8:53"
10, "1/16/2018 1:33"
11, "1/16/2018 2:28"
12, "1/16/2018 2:37"
13, "1/17/2018 1:17"
14, "1/17/2018 2:23"
15, "1/17/2018 4:33"
16, "1/17/2018 6:28"
17, "1/17/2018 6:28"
18, "1/17/2018 6:36"
19, "1/17/2018 6:38"
20, "1/17/2018 7:26"
21, "1/17/2018 7:28"
22, "1/17/2018 7:29"
23, "1/17/2018 7:46"
24, "1/17/2018 7:51"
25, "1/18/2018 2:22"
26, "1/18/2018 5:48"
27, "1/18/2018 5:50"
28, "1/18/2018 5:50"
29, "1/18/2018 5:51"
30, "1/18/2018 5:53"
100, "1/18/2018 10:32"
101, "1/18/2018 10:33"
102, "1/18/2018 10:33"
103, "1/18/2018 10:42"
104, "1/18/2018 10:59"
105, "1/18/2018 11:16"
```

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. dynamicFrame.show() is not printing anything. PrintSchema() works, and show() works if I convert to a spark dataframe. 
I have no idea why it is happening. In my particular case this is happening when I read in a json file compressed with gzip. It is not happening with uncompressed json files.
When I try to write the dynamicframe to S3 using **write_dynamic_frame.from_options** I get the following error

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 24.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 24.0

Comment: using jdbc where you are writing . It there data type  are validate on data on write .This issue looks there is issue in data

Comment: Are your job bookmarks enabled? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-toDF) for `DynamicFrame`, they're not very explicit about this but there can be cases where there is no underyling `DataFrame` processed until you call `toDF()`, so you are essentially calling `.show()` on something [which can be blank](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#printing-elements-of-an-rdd):

> To address these limitations, AWS Glue introduces the DynamicFrame. A
> DynamicFrame is similar to a DataFrame, except that each record is
> self-describing, so no schema is required initially. Instead, AWS Glue
> computes a schema on-the-fly when required, and explicitly encodes
> schema inconsistencies using a choice (or union) type. You can resolve
> these inconsistencies to make your datasets compatible with data
> stores that require a fixed schema.

**.toDF()**:

> Converts a DynamicFrame to an Apache Spark DataFrame by converting
> DynamicRecords into DataFrame fields. Returns the new DataFrame.

Checking the code here, it seems there could be instances where the underlying Java data frame is blank when you try to print it out: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/blob/f973095b9f2aa784cbcc87681a00da3127125337/awsglue/dynamicframe.py#L78

```
def show(self, num_rows=20):
    print(self._jdf.showString(num_rows))
```

where `__init__` relies on a passed in param (`jdf`) which could be not yet collected:

```
def __init__(self, jdf, glue_ctx, name=""):
    self._jdf = jdf
    self.glue_ctx = glue_ctx
    self._ssql_ctx = glue_ctx._ssql_ctx
    self._sc = glue_ctx and glue_ctx._sc
    self._schema = None
    self._lazy_rdd = None
    self.name = name
```

When calling `toDF()` the underlying dataframe is processed:

```
... SNIP ...
scala_options.append(self.glue_ctx.convert_resolve_option(option.path, option.action, option.target))

    return DataFrame(self._jdf.toDF(self.glue_ctx._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(scala_options)), self.glue_ctx)
```

The [Java docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#toDF(scala.collection.Seq)) for `.toDF()` mention this method converts from an RDD (i.e. it is collecting the results from the workers):

> This can be quite convenient in conversion from a RDD of tuples into a
> `DataFrame` with meaningful names.