# display DataFrame when using pyspark aws glue

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

how can I show the DataFrame with job etl of aws glue?

I tried this code below but doesn't display anything.

```
df.show()
```

**code**

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "flux-test", table_name = "tab1", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
sourcedf = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("id", "long", "id", "long"),("Rd.Id_Releve", "string", "Rd.Id_R", "string")])
 sourcedf = sourcedf.toDF()
 data = []
 schema = StructType(
[
    StructField('PM',
        StructType([
            StructField('Pf', StringType(),True),
            StructField('Rd', StringType(),True)
    ])
    ),
    ])
 cibledf = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, schema)
 cibledf = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(sourcedf.rdd.map(lambda x:    Row(PM=Row(Pf=str(x.id_prm), Rd=None ))), schema)
 print(cibledf.show())
 job.commit()
```

Comment: Did you check in the cloudwatch logs?

Comment: Can you verify if your source has data.Try printing Dynamic Frame contents before converting to data frame.

Comment: @Yuva yep I tried .. can you show me where the df have to be shown?? the interface? thank you

Comment: @Yuva maybe I need to delete job.commit in my job etl?

Answer (score 4):

In your glue console, after you run your glue job, in job listing there would be a column for Logs / Error logs.

Click on the Logs and this would take you to the cloudwatch logs associated to your job.  Browse though for the print statement.

also please check here: [Convert dynamic frame to a dataframe and do show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013334/spark-dynamic-frame-show-method-yields-nothing)

**ADDed working/test code sample**

Code sample:

```
zipcode_dynamicframe = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
       database = "customer_db",
       table_name = "zipcode_master")
zipcode_dynamicframe.printSchema()
zipcode_dynamicframe.toDF().show(10)
```

Screenshot for zipcode_dynamicframe.show() in cloudwatch log:

[image]

Comment: I did exactly what you said . didn't find data frame in the log. Thank you

Comment: added code snippet and a screenshot from the cloud watch log...the logs by default would be collapsed, and you have expand and look out for ur df.show().