# how to get familiar with logs in aws

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate, aws-glue

I'm new using awsglue.

I want to create logs on the cloudwatch. What can I do to go faster and see my log?

```
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
logger.info("Resultcount" + str(df.select(F.countDistinct(df.struct1.field1)).collect()[0][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything. By default AWS Glue creates log in the Cloudwatch.  Once you run the job, click on the logs against your job in the jobs history, and you can check for your print statement in the Cloudwatch.  [Please refer here for a sample cloudwatch log of dataframe.show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471577/display-dataframe-when-using-pyspark-aws-glue?noredirect=1#comment105169643_59471577)

Answer (score 0):

By default, print statements will appear in the error logs in cloudwatch.